# QT signal slot is not working

Tags: c++, qt

I am facing a strange problem while trying to execute the following program

**`main.cpp`**

```
#include "sample.h"
#include <QList>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  A a;
  a.callA();
  while(1)
    sleep(1);
  return 0;
}
```

sample.cpp

```
#include "sample.h"
#include <QList>
#include <QMetaMethod>
#include <unistd.h>


Thread::Thread(A *a)
{
}
void Thread::run()
{
  int i = 5;
  while (i){
    qDebug()<< i;
    sleep(2);
    i--;
  }
  emit processingDone(">>> FROM THREAD");
  qDebug()<<"Emited signal from thread";
}

void A::callA()
{
  qDebug()<<"from callA";
  //moveToThread(thread);
  thread->start();
  //thread->run();
  //emit signalA(">>> FROM CallA");
}

void A::slotA(QString arg)
{
  qDebug()<<"from sloatA "<< arg;
}
```

**`sample.h`**

```
class A;
    class Thread : public QThread
    {
      Q_OBJECT
    public:
      Thread(A *a);
      ~Thread(){
        qDebug()<<"Thread is destroyed";
      }
      void run();
    signals:
      void processingDone(QString arg);
    };

    class A : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
      A(){
        qDebug()<<"Registering";
        thread = new Thread(this);
        connect(thread, SIGNAL(processingDone(QString)), this, SLOT(slotA(QString)));
        connect(this,SIGNAL(signalA(QString)), this, SLOT(slotA(QString)));
      }
    public slots:
      void callA();
      void slotA(QString arg);

    signals:
      void signalA(QString arg);

    private:
      Thread *thread;
    };
```

When I try to executed the program, the slot is not getting invoked?
if I put moveToThraed(), then the code will work but that won't serve my puprose. Is anything i am missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not starting a main event loop.

your main function should look something like this:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
A a;
a.callA();
return app.exec();
```

Qt queued connections can't work if there is no event loop running in the receiving thread.

When the receiver object lives in a thread other than the thread where the signal is emitted, `Qt::AutoConnection` uses a `Qt::QueuedConnection`, see [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum).

A `Qt::QueuedConnection` works by posting an event to the event loop of the target thread (the thread where the receiver `QObject` lives). When that event is processed (by the event loop) the call to the slot is invoked in the target thread.

In your case, the main thread is always stuck in:

```
while(1)
    sleep(1);
```

So, it will never be able to execute anything else.

Comment: i didn't get you.

Comment: @Griffin It has to run in *all threads* that receive events. That will be usually the main thread, and any other thread that you moved `QObject`s to.

Comment: @Mike exec() is a blocking code. if i run in all threads, then when will the thread exit?

Comment: @Griffin , `exec()` is not blocking, it provides an event loop. The event loop waits until there are events to process (if there aren't any), and when events arrive it processes them, and goes back to the waiting state.

Comment: @Mike, Okey... is it possible to provide a event loop to thread created by pthread? My problem is in the application, main spawns a pthread, from this thread a QtObject is created and the objects starts a QThread. from this Qthread signal is emited, which is not received. is there a solution for this

Comment: @Mike doc says "int QThread::exec() : Enters the event loop and waits until exit() is called, returning the value that was passed to exit(). "

Comment: @Griffin , I think that this should be asked as a separate question, see[here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156902).Anyway, I think that having a `QEventLoop` running in your pthread can work.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Mike says, you need to start the main event loop of QT. Every QT application has this in their main:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
return a.exec();
```

In your case:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    A a;
    a.callA();
    return app.exec();
}
```